# Node.js creating model objects from json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, model, populate

I know that any json can be easily parsed into a javascript object, but let's say, I am using github API to get the profile of a couple developers, but I want to add to this objects some methods to process some data of those developers and keep the info within the object.

I know mongoose is a good extension that implements the concept of models that can do something similar to what I desire, but on a different approach, using as it uses a database to retrieve the models data. Is there a way to populate an array of models using a json returned from an API?

Maybe my way of approaching this matter is not correct, but I fail to see another way out of this issue.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is  what you are asking but you can parse JSON:

```
getSomethingFromAPI().then(function(dataResponse){
   var objectArray = JSON.parse(dataResponse)
})
```

If it isn't please post some code snippets and clarify your questions.

Per comment:  I don't think you can freely add an instance method without writing some code.  It could be as simple as taking the parse, and mapping that into instances (using underscore):

```
var someMethod = function(){
    return this.x
}

getSomethingFromAPI().then(function(dataResponse){
   var objectArray = _.map(JSON.parse(dataResponse), function(anObject){
      anObject.someMethod = someMethod.bind(anObject)
      return anObject
   })
})
```

There you could also instantiate object via constructors in the map,

```
getSomethingFromAPI().then(function(dataResponse){
   var objectArray = _.map(JSON.parse(dataResponse), function(anObject){
      return new SomeObjectConstructor(anObject.x, anObject.y)
   })
})
```

or perhaps there are more advanced techniques.  A functional approach would keep the data and the methods separated...

Comment: I know that I can parse JSON like that, but what I want to do is add a prototype function to all the objects parsed. so I could do something like: objectsArray[0].verify()

Comment: thanks a lot, completely forgot about map. that should do the trick nicely. thanks!